# How i can create more extended levels for NFT?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I create NFT

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JqmK.png

How i can create NFT levels like this ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg8kt.png

Im using python and brownie for compile and deploying smart-contract.

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the DNA algorithm.
In simple:

- Your NFT struct should contain a field like: NDA or characteristic
- The value of field above is: 0xAF125689
- Expose this field into your backend service
- You can split the value above into pairs [AF, 12, 56, 89], each pair identify for a property, can be level, skin...